# Push from the locally configured parse server

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I have configured the local parse server on my mac and am successfully able to install the device on the mongo database. But when I try to send a push from my device, the server throws an error

```
/parse/push  400 Bad Request
```

But I have noticed that sometimes the push gets registered on mongo database and parse.